# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on Vue.js

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, canvas, base64

I have a vue.js application which takes photo and sends it to a photo filter page. In this filter page i have a button to post the filtered photo. I can filter the taken pic but i cant post it. My error is here;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
```

And my code is here;

```
async sendPhoto () {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      canvas.width = document
        .getElementById('image')
        .getAttribute('data-original-width')
      canvas.height = document
        .getElementById('image')
        .getAttribute('data-original-height')
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.filter = this.filters.filter

      var img = document.createElement('img')
      img.src = this.image
      img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        const anchor = document.createElement('a')
        anchor.href = canvas.toDataURL()
        anchor.sendPhoto = this.img.src
        anchor.click()
      }
      console.log('canvas.toDataURL()', canvas.toDataURL())
      if (canvas.toDataURL() !== null && canvas.toDataURL() !== undefined) {
        const resBody = await this.$phoneAPI.imgYukle(canvas.toDataURL()) // burda filterli fotoyu tekrardan uploadlamak gerekiyo
        console.log('resBody', JSON.stringify(resBody))
        // await this.instagrampostStory({ message: canvas.toDataURL() })
        this.message = ''
      }
    },
    defaultImage () {
      return DefaultImage
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for helps !

Comment: What is the data type for `this.image`?

Comment: Its an uploaded screenshot. So its an url i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`drawImage` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), the first parameter takes an `HTMLImageElement`.

So, instead of

```
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) <-- change this line
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.href = canvas.toDataURL()
  anchor.sendPhoto = this.img.src
  anchor.click()
}
```

it should be

```
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)  <-- to this line
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.href = canvas.toDataURL()
  anchor.sendPhoto = this.img.src
  anchor.click()
}
```

Comment: Its okay i can get the filtered image now but how can i upload this image again to url ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the picture now but base64 image string is returning empty i couldnt fix it

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```